# Spring MVC Setting variable in session

Tags: java, spring, session

I am using Spring framework.
I want to set username in session, and want to display that user name in every jsp page.
What can I achieve this in any way....

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Consider checking the basic documentation for the Spring MVC framework before going on. It's a rather complex environment to start developing without (at least) a first read of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out the WebUtils setSessionAttribute method:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html#setSessionAttribute(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)